# Cant refresh longlistselector in WP8 Databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, data-binding, mvvm

I'm having some trouble with databinding to a LongListSelector. When I initally run this method, it works. The data is binded and everything is good.

The problem is when I press the refresh button, my app fetches a new JSON feed, parses it and tries to bind it. My app seems to download the JSON and stuff, but doesn't refresh the UI. Where have I gone wrong?

I've tried `BoardLongList.ItemsSource = null;` and `BoardLongList.ItemsSource.Clear();` to no avail.

Any ideas? The JObject is from newtonsoft.json and the RootObject is from ViewModels.RootObject.

Thanks in advance!

```
private void Bind(JObject rootObject)
{
    string rootObjectString = rootObject.ToString();                   
    RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(rootObjectString);

    // Bind to LongListSelector
    BoardLongList.ItemsSource = obj.Movements;
}
```

My XAML:

```
<phone:LongListSelector Grid.Row="1" x:Name="BoardLongList" Margin="0,0,-12,1" ItemsSource="{Binding Movement}">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2" Height="50">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                         <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                         <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                         <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                         <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding A1}" />
                     <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding A2}" />
                     <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"  Text="{Binding A3}" />
                     <TextBlock Grid.Column="3"  Text="{Binding A4}" />
                 </Grid>
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
     </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It was because of C# web caching my request. Not because of my databinding!

Answer (score 1):

Is your ItemsSource an ObservableCollection?.[`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is collection with notification that when something is changed in the collection, it notifies the UI.

Make obj.Movements an **ObservableCollection**

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the pull to refresh feature?

Check [this](https://gist.github.com/HamGuy/6018579) out!

You can accomplish this with the [ItemRealized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector.itemrealized%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) event and using a [ListHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector.listheader%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)(or [ListFooter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector.listfooter%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to pull from bottom). Within the ItemRealized event you check if the item is your header object. If it is then load more items.

Hope it helps.